# C++ Generic Function Parameter (different arguments)

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to write a benchmark function, but I need to be able to pass in any function to be tested. The functions that are being passed in are all of return type void, but their arguments vary. I'm sure this is a simple thing to do, but I'm not sure of the best way to approach it.

```
// 95% confidence interval
void benchmark(int n)
{
  int res[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    uint64_t start = GetTimeMs64();
    // **TODO: code to benchmark...**
    uint64_t end = GetTimeMs64();
    res[i] = end - start;
  }

  double avg = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) avg += res[i];
  avg /= double(n);

  double variance = 0.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    variance += ((res[i] - avg) * (res[i] - avg));
  }
  variance /= double(n - 1);
  cout << "Sample mean: " << avg << " +/- " << (1.96 * (sqrt(variance) / sqrt(n))) << endl;
}
```

For instance, I want to do something like:

```
void A(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
void B(int a) { return a * a; }
benchmark(100, A);
benchmark(100, B);
```

Comment: The basic idea is to lie to the compiler about the function's signature, call it with whatever arguments are appropriate, and hope you never make a mistake, because the compiler won't be able to help you.

Comment: Unless you're writing it for fun, have a look at [nonius](https://github.com/rmartinho/nonius), that aside you might be able to use some sort of type erasure to store the multi-signature functions and their arguments into a functors that all have the same signature.

Comment: Thanks, @ScottHunter! Something I totally didn't think about: it impacts the benchmarking results by ~10ms just because it's extra ops.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your `benchmark` function a template with something like the following

```
#include <utility>
void A(int, char) { }
void B(int) { }

template<typename... Args>
void benchmark(int n, void(&func)(Args...), Args&&... args)
{
  func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main()
{
  benchmark(1, A, 2, 'c');
  benchmark(1, B, 2);
}
```

If necessary you can make it even more generic by adding an extra template parameter for the return type.